# c# Xpath with multiple namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

Can somebody explain me please why this is not working?

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                        xmlDoc.Load("Bing2_ss.xml");

```
                    //Instantiate an XmlNamespaceManager object. 
                    XmlNamespaceManager xmlnsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
                    //Add the namespaces used in feed to the XmlNamespaceManager.
                    //xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("base", "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/Composite");
                    xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("m",   "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata");
                    xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("d",   "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/");
                    xmlnsManager.AddNamespace(String.Empty, "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");

                    XmlNodeList nodeList;
                    XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
                    nodeList = root.SelectNodes("//m:properties/d:WebTotal", xmlnsManager);
                    foreach (XmlNode nd in nodeList)
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine(nd.InnerText);
                    }
```

This is the original xml: http://gezond-afslanken.info/bing2_ss.xml

Comment: Do you get an error message at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra trailing slash on one of your namespaces. Try

```
xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("d","http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices");
```

Comment: Unbelievable...I copied it from the xml document it self. That stupid slash took me bussy for 3 hours! Tnx mate!